# run .profile function as cron job

Tags: cron, .profile

In the `.profile` file of the `root` user I have defined a function, e.g.

```
function printDate() {
  date
}
```

I want to run this function every minute and append the output to cron.log. I tried adding the following crontab entry:

```
* * * * * printDate > $HOME/cron.log 2>&1
```

But it doesn't work. The `cron.log` file gets created, but it's empty. I guess this is because the `.profile` isn't read by cron, so any functions/aliases defined therein are unavailable to it. So I tried changing the crontab entry to:

```
* * * * * source $HOME/.profile;printDate >> $HOME/cron.log 2>&1
```

But this doesn't work either. It seems cron still doesn't have access to the `printDate` function because I see the following in `cron.log`

```
/bin/sh: printDate: not found
```

Comment: look here http://superuser.com/questions/106272/how-to-call-bash-functions

Comment: So, to clarify: `source $HOME/.profile; printDate > $HOME/cron.log 2>&1` should do it :)

Comment: @SirCharlo will this append the output to `cron.log` or overwrite it?

Comment: The `>` operator overwrites; the `>>` operator appends.. Sorry, I had missed that part of your post. So it should be: `source $HOME/.profile; printDate >> $HOME/cron.log 2>&1`

Comment: @SirCharlo it still doesn't work, I've updated my question with further details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wrap it in another bash script.  Your file names will be different, but I have:
test(.profile)

```
#!/bin/bash
function printDate() {
  date
}
```

wrap(a new script you can put wherever, just change the url)

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/
source ./test
printDate > ./date.log
```

when run from a /bin/sh

```
$ ls
test  wrap
$ ./wrap
$ cat date.log
Wed Apr 11 11:49:39 EDT 2012
$
```

Now just make sure your paths/environment are right

The crontab lines I just tested were:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
HOME=/root
* * * * * $HOME/wrap >/dev/null 2>&1
```